# Random freezes across OS'

Tags: diagnostic

My computer has an issue that it randomly freezes. I've faced this issue for years across Ubuntu versions and Windows versions. I'm currently running 19.04. I've faced this issue with 16.04, Windows 10 and Windows 7.
Is there a tool that I can use to diagnose the problem?

Phoronix output:

```
  PROCESSOR:          Intel Core i7 930 @ 2.79GHz
    Core Count:       4                     
    Thread Count:     8                     
    Extensions:       SSE 4.2               
    Cache Size:       8192 KB               
    Microcode:        0x1d                  
    Scaling Driver:   acpi-cpufreq ondemand 

  GRAPHICS:           Gigabyte NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 2GB
    Frequency:        810/666MHz       
    OpenGL:           4.6.0            
    Display Driver:   NVIDIA 390.116   
    Monitor:          SyncMaster       
    Screen:           1920x1080        

  MOTHERBOARD:        Gigabyte X58A-UD3R
    BIOS Version:     FA                           
    Chipset:          Intel 5520/5500/X58 + ICH10R 
    Audio:            Realtek ALC889               
    Network:          Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411    

  MEMORY:             6144MB

  DISK:               1000GB Western Digital WD10EZEX-08M + 2000GB Western Digital WD20EARX-00P
    File-System:      ext4                          
    Mount Options:    errors=remount-ro relatime rw 
    Disk Scheduler:   MQ-DEADLINE                   

  OPERATING SYSTEM:   Ubuntu 19.04
    Kernel:           5.0.0-13-generic (x86_64)                                                         
    Desktop:          GNOME Shell 3.32.0                                                                
    Display Server:   X Server 1.20.4                                                                   
    Compiler:         GCC 8.3.0                                                                         
    Security:         KPTI                                                                              
                      + __user pointer sanitization                                                     
                      + Full generic retpoline IBPB: conditional IBRS_FW STIBP: conditional RSB filling 
                      + SSB disabled via prctl and seccomp                                              
                      + PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes SMT vulnerable                    


     CPU Temperature: 54.00 C   CPU Usage (Summary): 12.69 %  
     GPU Temperature: 49.00 C             GPU Usage: 3     %  
        Memory Usage: 2169  MB         System Uptime 26
```

Comment: For starters I'd use the memory test tool provided on most Ubuntu install media, then do a cap-check of the device - but most of this is off-topic being about hardware diagnostics.